# How can I solve this: "The page was not displayed because the request entity is too large."

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, iis-7

Win 7. 64-bit.This also initially happened on my previous XP machine. In both cases, the website loaded with no problem, in the case of XP, for years, in the case of Win 7, for about 4 months.

Is is also happening when I use IE.

I have searched the net for many weeks now and I cannot understand how to fix this. All sites I have gone to suggest that it is iis that has to be modified. It happens on one website only: www.ttc.ca. I am grateful for help, thanks.

Comment: Is it only on the combination of Chrome and Windows 7? (Tested on Windows 8.1 and Chrome - the page loads fine, unless you need to click on some particular link to get that error)

Comment: THis is the exact link, but none work for me. https://www.ttc.ca/Routes/82/Westbound.jsp  I had XP and this happened. Then I switched to Win 7 about 5 months ago and all was fine. Then about 3 weeks ago it happened again. I cannot access this website.

Comment: No issue with Windows 8 / 8.1 (both 64bit) and chrome (32-bit).. even on that particular page. I wonder if some combination of OS and Browser? (Windows 7...32 bit or 64 bit?) - I'll try to test using a different machine that runs Win7 and report back.

Comment: 64 bit. Thanks I'll add that to the question. It is some sort of random thing as I tried to make clear in the question, but once it happens, it always happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the Microsoft friendly description of a standard HTTP error (413) and it means the server did not like the size of your HTTP request.

What can you do about the size of your HTTP requests in most browsers?  Nothing really, so it's likely a mistake on the server end.

I would imagine you might see if you try to access URLs that are meant for API usage, i.e. meant not accessed via your browser but accessed via an app or program.  You shouldn't ever see this by clicking a link on your browser normally, though, unless you have extensions or addons that are messing with the HTTP request going to the server - unless the site developer was lazy or OK with you receiving HTTP errors like that.

If you have an add-on modifying your User Agent string, and did something funny like set the string to the contents of an entire text or other document, that could be a cause ...

So most likely something on the server end is wrong and whoever runs the server needs to fix or update the program generating web pages for that particular URL.

---

EDIT: As @Daniel B mentions below in the comments (something I didn't think about!) - cookies are part of the request.  Clearing them (either for the specific site, or all of them if you are not sure) will reduce the length of your HTTP request if there are stale cookies for the site you are trying to visit.

Comment: There is one thing, though: Cookies. If a remote service heavily relies on cookie and/or is malfunctioning, their data size can be quite large.

Comment: Thanks both. When this first happened on my XP machine, I contacted the TTC. I received a response that there must be something wrong with my machine, it was not their responsibility. As to the comment by Daniel B, I am unsure what you mean. Is there some way I can alter that? 3rdly, AFASIK, I have not modified any User Agent string, I wouldn't know how.

Comment: @Xavierjazz Sure, clear the site’s cookies in your browser. If you’re unsure, just remove all cookies. Cookies are sent as part of the HTTP request headers, which is subject to more limitations than the request body, which follows after the headers.

Comment: @Daniel b: It worked, it worked it worked! So simple. Thanks a lot!!! Please add this as an answer.

Comment: Nah, just accept this answer. It has all the details on how this message is an IIS custom message for error 413. I’m just familiar with the whole cookies problem because vBulletin uses them extensively to store read/unread info per thread to lessen database load.